# Convert drawing math function from ChartJs 2 to 3

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have following JSON chart configuration which is working fine on chartjs2:

```
{
    "type": "line",
    "data": {
        "labels": [0, 100],
        "datasets": [{
            "label": "T = const",
            "function": "function(x) { return 2; }",
            "data": [],
            "fill": false,
            "borderColor": "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
            "tension": 0.1
        }]
    },
    "options": {
        "scales": 
        {
            "x": { "title": { "display": true, "text": "[n]" }},
            "y": { "title": { "display": true, "text": "[u]" }}
        }
    },
    "plugins": [{
        "beforeInit": function(chart) {
          // We get the chart data
          var data = chart.config.data;
  
          // For every dataset ...
          for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
  
              // For every label ...
              for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {
  
                  // We get the dataset's function and calculate the value
                  var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
                      x = data.labels[j],
                      y = fct(x);
                  // Then we add the value to the dataset data
                  data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
              }
          }
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Error: fct is not a function
```

How convert this example to make it working with ChartJs 3? I guess something has changed in `chart` API, but I cannot figure out what exactly and how to apply it to my `datasets` example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could fix it easy yourself, by removing the quotes, since currently it is not a function, it's only a string:

```
 "function": "function(x) { return 2; }",
```

to

```
 "function": function(x) { return 2; },
```

In the dataset

```
 ...
 "datasets": [{
     "label": "T = const",
     "function": function(x) { return 2; },
     "data": [],
     "fill": false,
     "borderColor": "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
     "tension": 0.1
}]
...
```